# proftpd: virtual users access via SFTP with ssh keys, password

Tags: ssh, sftp, proftpd

I encountered a problem with authenticating virtual users. The documentation lists various methods, such as password or key, or both. Indicates the virtual host. Is it possible to split the authentication method within virtual users and not within the virtual host as a whole, so that, for example, some users are authenticated by a password, and others by a key+password pair within a single virtual host?